# How to make text not to break outside the div

Tags: javascript, html, css

The html card looks like this:

```html
<li class="col-md-4">
  <div class="categorylist-item">
    <a class="cid-201728169" href="xxxxxxxx">
      <h4>Backoffice</h4>
      <div class="linebreak"></div>
      <p class="description">Ordrar, leveranser, inventering, kampanjer, bokföring m.m.</p> 
      <!--<p class="readmore">Läs mer</p>-->
    </a>
  </div>
</li>
```

```
.container.home .categorylist-item h4 {
  font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.container.home .categorylist-item .description {
  display: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight:400;
  margin-top:15px;
}

.container.home .categorylist-item:hover .description {
  display: block;
}

.container.home .categorylist-item .readmore {
  font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: 500;
  color: #212529;
  display:none;
}

.container.home .categorylist-item:hover .readmore {
  display:block;
}

.container.home .categorylist-item .readmore:after {
  content: " \00bb";
}

/*Columns on startpage transitions*/

.categorylist-item .cid-201728169 { /*First column transition*/
    -moz-transform: translateY(100%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(100%);
    transform: translateY(100%);
  transition: .5s;
}

.categorylist-item:hover .cid-201728169,/*First column transition*/
.categorylist-item .cid-201728169 {
    -moz-transform: translateY(0);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    -ms-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
}
```

Dont bother to run it...

A simple visualisation of it:

This is when you don't hover the card:

[image]

When you hover the card:

[image]

The problem is:

[image]

The `p` tag (description) goes outside of the box.

How do I make the text not to break outside the div..?

Any ideas?

Comment: can you add all code in codePen or somthing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question *'How do I make the text not to break outside the div'*, you can set `overflow : hidden` on the container for the description. That will prevent text from going outside the container. This will cause the element to overflow when bounds are being violated and stay hidden under its bounding boxes. No scroll bar will be shown even if its beyond bounds, but the content will be scrollable.

This will not be an ideal solution though. The description will get hidden, fully or partially, if it crosses bounds and the user might not know to scroll on top of it to read it.

Best solution for you would be adjust the elements' size/margin/padding so that there is enough space for the description.